# A question about $2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is the cardinality of the infinite sequences consisting of $\left\{0,1\right\}$ or $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ or $\left\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,9 \right\}$ elements equal to the cardinality of the infinite sequences consisting of elements $\left\{0,1\right\}$?

I mean, is this correct?

> $$card \left(2^{\mathbb{N}}\right)=card \left(3^{\mathbb{N}}\right)=card \left(4^{\mathbb{N}}\right)=\cdots=card \left(9^{\mathbb{N}}\right)=2^{\aleph_0}$$

If correct, where can I find proof of that?

Comment: It is correct. I’m pretty sure this has been asked about this week on this site, and many times before that. Did nothing related come up in the side bar when you wrote the question? (I’m on my phone or I’d duplicate search.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\alpha^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ for all $2\le\alpha\le 2^{\aleph_0}$. This is due to the identity $\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0$ and inequalities $$2^{\aleph_0}\le \alpha^{\aleph_0}\le \left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0^2}=2^{\aleph_0}$$